# Hibernate HQL works on MySQL but doesnt work on MSSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, playframework, playframework-1.x

i am working on a Play Framework 1.2.4 project.

My development computer has mySql installedand i am using it, Production enviroment has MS-SQL2005.

I have to use some sort of HQL in my batch operations. The select and delete queries work fine on mysql but in ms-sql the queries doesnt seem to work. Heres my code:

```
              stateless.createQuery("delete INVENTORY inv where product <>:product and station=:station")
          .setParameter("product", lpgProd)
          .setParameter("station", inv.station)
          .executeUpdate();
          int count = stateless.createQuery("from INVENTORY where itemid = :itemid").setParameter("itemid", inv.getId()).list().size();
          if(count==0)
              stateless.insert(inv);
```

This code basically checks if there are any older records on the database before writing. I am also using "stateless session" for faster batch operations.

The problem is, in MS-SQL, these codes do nothing. it doesnt delete any records and doesnt return any result from the list.

Anything besides hql queries work fine. (i.e. sateless.insert(inv))

What shold i do?

Comment: and you have set the correct hibernate dialect?

Comment: Try to log sql coming to database - there could be useful information about your problem.  Sometimes there is a clash with reserwed words

Comment: umesh! thanks for reminding me that! i've set jpa.dialect but didnt set up the hibernate.dialect in application.conf file. its now working, thanks!!!